# Is there a way to put figures and a longtable side by side?

Tags: floats, longtable

I have several narrow `longtables` on my document and I would like to use the white space on their side to place pictures (or eventually some text) but I couldn't figure out how to do it. I tried nesting pictures and longtable in another longtable but I think that's not possible. I also thought about `minipage` but that does not work either since minipages do no span on multiple pages.

The following picture shows what I want to achieve.

[image]

And here is the code I used to produce the document I then edited to get the picture.

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{longtable, booktabs}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-3]

\begin{longtable}{|l|r|}
\toprule
Column 1 & Column 2\\
\midrule
\endhead
text 1 & text 2\\
text 1 & text 2\\
text 1 & text 2\\
text 1 & text 2\\
text 1 & text 2\\
text 1 & text 2\\
text 1 & text 2\\
text 1 & text 2\\
text 1 & text 2\\
text 1 & text 2\\
text 1 & text 2\\
text 1 & text 2\\
text 1 & text 2\\
text 1 & text 2\\
text 1 & text 2\\
text 1 & text 2\\
text 1 & text 2\\
text 1 & text 2\\
text 1 & text 2\\
text 1 & text 2\\
text 1 & text 2\\
text 1 & text 2\\
text 1 & text 2\\
text 1 & text 2\\
text 1 & text 2\\
text 1 & text 2\\
text 1 & text 2\\
text 1 & text 2\\
text 1 & text 2\\
text 1 & text 2\\
text 1 & text 2\\\bottomrule
\caption{Something}
\end{longtable}


\begin{figure}[!h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width = 0.4\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Picture A}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width = 0.4\textwidth]{example-image-b}
    \caption{Picture B}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Comment: put the images in a new first column (you can use `\captionof{figure}{...` if you need a caption (capt-of package)

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Excuse my ignorance, but you mean to use ```\multirow``` and to put the figures inside a single big cell in the new first column? It would make sense but I wasn't really able to get it to work: I get the two pictures side by side instead of one on top of the other and also ```\captionof``` seem not to be working inside ```\multirow```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This overlaps the left margin of longtable, increasing `\LTleft` accordingly.  You can only put the figures into the header twice: `firsthead` and `head`.  Longtable does not allow dynamic headers or footers.  After that you have to add them to the correct row.

Note: using caption instead of capt-of will misalign the table caption.

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{longtable, booktabs}
\usepackage{capt-of}

\newsavebox{\tempboxa}
\newsavebox{\tempboxb}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-3]

\savebox{\tempboxa}{\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width = \linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \captionof{figure}{Picture A}
\end{minipage}}%
\savebox{\tempboxb}{\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width = \linewidth]{example-image-b}
    \captionof{figure}{Picture B}
\end{minipage}}%

\addtolength{\LTleft}{\dimexpr 0.5\textwidth-\tabcolsep}
\begin{longtable}{|l|r|}
\toprule
\llap{\raisebox{-\height}[0pt][0pt]{\box\tempboxa}\hspace{0.1\textwidth}}Column 1 & Column 2\\
\midrule
\endfirsthead
\toprule
\llap{\raisebox{-\height}[0pt][0pt]{\box\tempboxb}\hspace{0.1\textwidth}}Column 1 & Column 2\\
\midrule
\endhead
\midrule
\endfoot
\bottomrule
\caption{Something}
\endlastfoot
text 1 & text 2\\
text 1 & text 2\\
text 1 & text 2\\
text 1 & text 2\\
text 1 & text 2\\
text 1 & text 2\\
text 1 & text 2\\
text 1 & text 2\\
text 1 & text 2\\
text 1 & text 2\\
text 1 & text 2\\
text 1 & text 2\\
text 1 & text 2\\
text 1 & text 2\\
text 1 & text 2\\
text 1 & text 2\\
text 1 & text 2\\
text 1 & text 2\\
text 1 & text 2\\
text 1 & text 2\\
text 1 & text 2\\
text 1 & text 2\\
text 1 & text 2\\
text 1 & text 2\\
text 1 & text 2\\
text 1 & text 2\\
text 1 & text 2\\
text 1 & text 2\\
text 1 & text 2\\
text 1 & text 2\\
text 1 & text 2\\
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your clever solution! Was about to say that in couple of case I wouldn't been able to use it, namely when ```longtable``` doesn't actually span two pages and when I have more than two pictures, but I then realized that every ```savebox``` can contain multiple pictures! Brilliant! The only "disadvantage" is that pictures have to be placed manually in the correct box, but in my case this will work no problem! Thank you again!